What are anchor channels and how does Electrum Trampoline solve lack of them?
While trying to set up a lightning channel, I came across this issue. Here's the suggested solution:

The acinq node now requires anchor channels, which are not supported yet in Electrum. (will be in 4.6) You can still open a channel with the Electrum trampoline.

What are anchor channels and how does Electrum Trampoline solve lack of them?
